# Identifying a component with only a partial part number

Tags: identification, flipflop

I have taken apart some circuitry that no longer works and I accidentally went a bit too far with the dremel. This means I've partially obscured the serial number of a component i'm wishing to identify.

Here is a picture:
[image]

There's 3 lines of text as far as I can see on the component in the centre.

- The 1st being (I think) EL1738
- 2nd NY135 (maybe)
- 3rd SSU

I've tried punching these into google without much luck.

The device itself switches on a coil every other time a hall effect sensor is triggered. My first thoughts are that this might be some sort of flip flop.

What id like to know is what else can I do in order to identify this component?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That's most likely an **ATM**EL **ATTI**NY13S **-10**SSU. (or -20SSU)

It's a µC with integrated flash ROM. You had to read out that flash ROM (if enabled) to make a replacement part function at this place. A part off the shelf comes empty and will not function.

Comment: That makes sense to me actually. I could probably program it myself.

Comment: Yeah, but you had to read out the flash ROM of the existing part first, so you have the program needed. Or you develop new software yourself.

Comment: I can develop the software myself. its a simple program needed to act as a flip flop. The only thing that doesnt quite fit are the pin outs. The top left is ground or VCC and the 2nd from the bottom left is ground or VCC which doesnt match up to the ATTINY 13

Comment: See that tiny capacitor right next to the chip? That one connects Vdd and GND for a stable power supply at high switching speeds. One lead goes to pin 4, which matches the ATtiny13. Check where the other lead goes to.

Comment: I see now, Thats correct. Thanks for helping me ID this.

Comment: You are welcome.